# I want to use document.getElementById("ID_NAME").innerHTML = <Text>hello world</Text> in react native?

Tags: xcode, react-native, getelementbyid

I have two components, parent and child.
In parent I have header.In children I have two views.
If one button in child is pressed then it will change to another view.
If it is another view I want to hide the header from parent

```
    componentDidMount(){
      document.getElementById("ID_NAME").innerHTML = <Text>hello world</Text>
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <Text id="ID_NAME"></Text>
      )
    }
```

I want to call that Text element and change its value
**The element is in another component where props cannot be passed**

Answer (score 1):

When working with React / React Native you should forget everything (almost) you know about html / css.

This class will do what you want to achieve. You should read the [React Native docs and tutorials](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial)

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    idName: '',
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ idName: 'hello world' })
  }

  render() {
    return (<Text>{this.state.idName}</Text>)
  }
}
```

Comment: Can u please suggest,The element is present in another component,where props cannot be passed @poptocrack

Comment: You should take a look at the context api then. Easy to put in place.

Comment: Can you please share the link bro @poptocrack